# unfolding as resolution

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, homological-algebra, heuristics

Has anyone described 'unfolding' as used in mathematical physics (e.g. on-shell AND off-shell) as analogous to a resolution in algebra - higher derivatives are unfolded in terms of new variables?

Comment: Hi Jim, do you have a reference where this term is used and applied? Is it a vague general procedure or is it reasonably well defined (for mathematical physics, that is)?

Comment: I believe he is referring the the procedure by which you expand a higher-order differential equation as a first order equation in more variables, by introducing new variables like "$k$th derivative of $x$".

Comment: I've always associated that with blowups.